# Run sequence automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so i want a html page with one button. When i press the button i want the page where my button is to close, and my javascript sequence to run. When i have arrived at youtube.com (after 10sec) i want that window to close.

Does anybody know if this will work?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

        var my_window;

        function OpenWin()
        {
            my_window=window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=1000, height=800, top=10, left=10");
            setTimeout("GoUrl('http://www.youtube.com')", 10000);

        }
        function GoUrl(Url)
        {
            my_window.location=Url;
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="OpenWin()">Open Window</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: Java and JavaScript are different.

Comment: Does it work when you try it?

Comment: Where is your script closing the window with the button? That won't work -- once you close a window, all scripts associated with that window stop running.

Comment: @Bamar, ok then the first window (with the button) can stay the whole sequence. Can i close the two windows after the sequence then?

Comment: The javascript on the first page won't be able to affect the second window. Load a div popup with an iframe and do it all from there.

Comment: @malcoda, do you wanna show me? Im new with this sort of coding!

Comment: What is the workflow you're trying to achieve? Button click -> modal with youtube (or youtube video?) -> ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be possible to close the window that contains the button unless that window itself is opened with a script. See the documentation on window.close():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close

It is possible to close my_window, however, since it is created with window.open(). If you want my_window to close after some period of time, try something like:

```
var my_window;

function OpenWin()
{
    my_window=window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=1000, height=800, top=10, left=10");
    setTimeout("GoUrl('http://www.youtube.com')", 10000);

}
function GoUrl(Url)
{
    my_window.location=Url;
    setTimeout(function () { my_window.close(); }, 10000);
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that it is considered bad practice to pass code strings to setTimeout, since it's just like eval(). Instead of passing in "GoURL('...')", try using a callback function instead, like the other use of setTimeout shown above.

setTimeout:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout